# Delete spacing and center text

Tags: html, css, html-email

I'm trying to delete the dark grey spacing from underneath the first and second black blocks but without much success.

Also I want to center the text from the third block within the block.

I've tried to play with the height and width of the blocks but I can't get to the result that I want.

I really appreciate any suggestions, thanks in advance.

```html
<div style="float: left; width: 100%" class="sapMktBlock">
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="min-width:100%;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="font-size:0px" class="nomob">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="640" align="center" style="width:640px;min-width:640px;" class="wrapto320px">
      <table role="presentation" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="min-width:100%; " class="wrapto320px">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td align="left">
          <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th bgcolor="#3B3B3C" class="colsplit" style="width:213px;">
              <table width="100%" style="min-width:100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td align="left" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;">
                  <a href=""><img src="https://dummyimage.com/540x500/000/fff&amp;text=left" width="270" height="auto" style="display:block;height:auto;" class="nomob" alt="1976"></a>
                  <div style="width:0; overflow:hidden; float:left; display:none; max-height:0px; mso-hide:all;" class="show">
                    <a href=""> <img src="https://i1.adis.ws/i/thebodyshop/UK_trigger_WelcomeCJ_Day0_GroupADiscount_story_1976mob" width="1" style="display:block;" class="wrapto100pc" alt="1976"> </a>
                  </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                
                <tr>
                  <td align="center" valign="top">
                  <table width="100%" style="min-width:100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:0px 20px 10px 20px;">
                      <table width="100%" style="min-width:100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

                      </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              </th>
              <th bgcolor="#3B3B3C" class="colsplit" style="width:100px; vertical-align: top;">
              <table width="100%" style="min-width:100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;">
                  <a href=""><img alt="1996" class="nomob" style="display:block;height:auto;" height="auto" width="100" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x500/000/fff&amp;text=middle"></a>
                  <div style="width:0; overflow:hidden; float:left; display:none; max-height:0px; mso-hide:all;" class="show">
                    <a href=""> <img src="https://i1.adis.ws/i/thebodyshop/UK_trigger_WelcomeCJ_Day0_GroupADiscount_story_1996mob" width="1" style="display:block;" class="wrapto100pc" alt="1996"> </a>
                  </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                
                <tr>
                  <td align="center" valign="top">
                  <table width="100%" style="min-width:100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:0px 20px 10px 20px;">
                      <table width="100%" style="min-width:100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

                      </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              </th>
              <th bgcolor="#3B3B3C" class="colsplit" style="width:365px;vertical-align: top;">
              <table width="100%" style="min-width:100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;">
                  <span style="white-space: normal;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa </span>
                  <div style="width:0; overflow:hidden; float:left; display:none; max-height:0px; mso-hide:all;" class="show">
                    <a href=""> <img src="https://i1.adis.ws/i/thebodyshop/UK_trigger_WelcomeCJ_Day0_GroupADiscount_story_1998mob" width="1" style="display:block;" class="wrapto100pc" alt="1998"> </a>
                  </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                 
                  <tr><td align="center" valign="top">
                  <table width="100%" style="min-width:100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:0px 20px 10px 20px;">
                      <table width="100%" style="min-width:100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

                      </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              </th>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      </td>
      <td style="font-size:0px" class="nomob">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you're looking for:

```html
<div style="float: left; width: 100%" class="sapMktBlock">
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="min-width:100%;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="font-size:0px" class="nomob">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="640" align="center" style="width:640px;min-width:640px;" class="wrapto320px">
      <table role="presentation" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="min-width:100%; " class="wrapto320px">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td align="left">
          <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th bgcolor="#3B3B3C" class="colsplit" style="width:213px;">
              <table width="100%" style="min-width:100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td align="left" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;">
                  <a href=""><img src="https://dummyimage.com/540x500/000/fff&amp;text=left" width="270" height="auto" style="display:block;height:auto;" class="nomob" alt="1976"></a>
                  <div style="width:0; overflow:hidden; float:left; display:none; max-height:0px; mso-hide:all;" class="show">
                    <a href=""> <img src="https://i1.adis.ws/i/thebodyshop/UK_trigger_WelcomeCJ_Day0_GroupADiscount_story_1976mob" width="1" style="display:block;" class="wrapto100pc" alt="1976"> </a>
                  </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              </th>
              <th bgcolor="#3B3B3C" class="colsplit" style="width:100px; vertical-align: top;">
              <table width="100%" style="min-width:100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;">
                  <a href=""><img alt="1996" class="nomob" style="display:block;height:auto;" height="auto" width="100" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x500/000/fff&amp;text=middle"></a>
                  <div style="width:0; overflow:hidden; float:left; display:none; max-height:0px; mso-hide:all;" class="show">
                    <a href=""> <img src="https://i1.adis.ws/i/thebodyshop/UK_trigger_WelcomeCJ_Day0_GroupADiscount_story_1996mob" width="1" style="display:block;" class="wrapto100pc" alt="1996"> </a>
                  </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              </th>
              <th bgcolor="#3B3B3C" class="colsplit" style="width:365px;vertical-align: top;padding:5px">
              <table width="100%" style="min-width:100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;">
                  <span style="white-space: normal;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa </span>
                  <div style="width:0; overflow:hidden; float:left; display:none; max-height:0px; mso-hide:all;" class="show">
                    <a href=""> <img src="https://i1.adis.ws/i/thebodyshop/UK_trigger_WelcomeCJ_Day0_GroupADiscount_story_1998mob" width="1" style="display:block;" class="wrapto100pc" alt="1998"> </a>
                  </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                 
                  <tr><td align="center" valign="top">
                  <table width="100%" style="min-width:100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:0px 20px 10px 20px;">
                      <table width="100%" style="min-width:100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

                      </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              </th>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      </td>
      <td style="font-size:0px" class="nomob">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: can I ask you what did you change please

Comment: Underneath issue is solved and the text on the right is exactly centered in his visible space, does this answer miss anything?

Comment: no, the solution is perfect but I wanted to know what have you change so I can learn too

Comment: Well, with a code analysis, it's possible to see that I've removed first the code included in the last `<tr>
                  <td align="center" valign="top">
                  <table width="100%" style="min-width:100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">` and also the code contained in `<th bgcolor="#3B3B3C" class="colsplit" style="width:365px;vertical-align: top;">`

Answer (score 0):

Well I hope that I did unterstand you well
Actually i found that there are some `<tr>` that you don't need and then I add `style="text-align:center;"` to put your text int the center

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div style="float: left; width: 100%" class="sapMktBlock">
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="min-    width:100%;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-size:0px" class="nomob">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td width="640" align="center" style="width:640px;min-width:640px;" class="wrapto320px">
                        <table role="presentation" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="min-width:100%; " class="wrapto320px">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="left">
                                        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th bgcolor="#3B3B3C" class="colsplit" style="width:213px;">
                                                        <table width="100%" style="min-width:100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                            <tbody>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                <td align="left" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;">
                                                                    <a href=""><img src="https://dummyimage.com/540x500/000/fff&amp;text=left" width="270" height="auto" style="display:block;height:auto;" class="nomob" alt="1976"></a>
                                                                    <div style="width:0; overflow:hidden; float:left; display:none; max-height:0px; mso-hide:all;" class="show">
                                                                        <a href=""> <img src="https://i1.adis.ws/i/thebodyshop/UK_trigger_WelcomeCJ_Day0_GroupADiscount_story_1976mob" width="1" style="display:block;" class="wrapto100pc" alt="1976"> </a>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </th>
                                                <th bgcolor="#3B3B3C" class="colsplit" style="width:100px; vertical-align: top;">
                                                    <table width="100%" style="min-width:100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;">
                                                                    <a href=""><img alt="1996" class="nomob" style="display:block;height:auto;" height="auto" width="100" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x500/000/fff&amp;text=middle"></a>
                                                                    <div style="width:0; overflow:hidden; float:left; display:none; max-height:0px; mso-hide:all;" class="show">
                                                                        <a href=""> <img src="https://i1.adis.ws/i/thebodyshop/UK_trigger_WelcomeCJ_Day0_GroupADiscount_story_1996mob" width="1" style="display:block;" class="wrapto100pc" alt="1996"> </a>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>

                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </th>
                                                <th bgcolor="#3B3B3C" class="colsplit" style="width:365px;vertical-align: top;">
                                                    <table width="100%" style="min-width:100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;">
                                                                    <div style="white-space: normal;text-align:center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa </div>
                                                                    <div style="width:0; overflow:hidden; float:left; display:none; max-height:0px; mso-hide:all;" class="show">
                                                                        <a href=""> <img src="https://i1.adis.ws/i/thebodyshop/UK_trigger_WelcomeCJ_Day0_GroupADiscount_story_1998mob" width="1" style="display:block;" class="wrapto100pc" alt="1998"> </a>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                        </td>
                    <td style="font-size:0px" class="nomob">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can I ask you what did you change please

Comment: So I removed the 3 parts of `<td></td>` in order to remove delete dark grey spacing and I added the `text-align:center` in order to center the text

Answer (score -1):

Is that you want.

```html
<div style="float: left; width: 100%" class="sapMktBlock">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="min-width:100%;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="font-size:0px" class="nomob">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="640" align="center" style="width:640px;min-width:640px;" class="wrapto320px">
          <table role="presentation" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="min-width:100%; " class="wrapto320px">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td align="left">
                  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <th bgcolor="#3B3B3C" class="colsplit" style="width:213px;">
                          <table width="100%" style="min-width:100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td align="left" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;">
                                  <a href=""><img src="https://dummyimage.com/540x500/000/fff&amp;text=left" width="270" height="auto" style="display:block;height:auto;" class="nomob" alt="1976"></a>
                                  <div style="width:0; overflow:hidden; float:left; display:none; max-height:0px; mso-hide:all;" class="show">
                                    <a href=""><img src="https://i1.adis.ws/i/thebodyshop/UK_trigger_WelcomeCJ_Day0_GroupADiscount_story_1976mob" width="1" style="display:block;" class="wrapto100pc" alt="1976"> </a>
                                  </div>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                                                            
                              <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top">
                                  <table width="100%" style="min-width:100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                    <tbody>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:0px 20px 10px 20px;">
                                          <table width="100%" style="min-width:100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"></table>
                                        </td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                  </table>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </th>
                        <th bgcolor="#3B3B3C" class="colsplit" style="width:100px; vertical-align: top;">
                          <table width="100%" style="min-width:100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;">
                                  <a href=""><img alt="1996" class="nomob" style="display:block;height:auto;" height="auto" width="100" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x500/000/fff&amp;text=middle"></a>
                                  <div style="width:0; overflow:hidden; float:left; display:none; max-height:0px; mso-hide:all;" class="show">
                                    <a href=""><img src="https://i1.adis.ws/i/thebodyshop/UK_trigger_WelcomeCJ_Day0_GroupADiscount_story_1996mob" width="1" style="display:block;" class="wrapto100pc" alt="1996"></a>
                                  </div>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top">
                                  <table width="100%" style="min-width:100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                    <tbody>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:0px 20px 10px 20px;">
                                          <table width="100%" style="min-width:100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"></table>
                                        </td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                  </table>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </th>
                        <th bgcolor="#3B3B3C" class="colsplit" style="width:365px;vertical-align: middle;padding-left: 20px;">
                          <table width="100%" style="min-width:100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;">
                                  <span style="white-space: normal;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa </span>
                                    <div style="width:0; overflow:hidden; float:left; display:none; max-height:0px; mso-hide:all;" class="show">
                                      <a href=""> <img src="https://i1.adis.ws/i/thebodyshop/UK_trigger_WelcomeCJ_Day0_GroupADiscount_story_1998mob" width="1" style="display:block;" class="wrapto100pc" alt="1998"> </a>
                                    </div>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                                                           
                                <tr>
                                  <td align="center" valign="top">
                                    <table width="100%" style="min-width:100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                      <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:0px 20px 10px 20px;">
                                            <table width="100%" style="min-width:100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"</table>
                                          </td>
                                        </tr>
                                      </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                          </th>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
          <td style="font-size:0px" class="nomob">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

try this.

Comment: there is still the grey margin underneath the first and second block, I want them to be shorten as the third block and not just put the black bground color to the first and the second block